# Dynamic accordion with Jade not working

Tags: jquery, html, pug, accordion, jquery-ui-accordion

I am trying to create a dynamic accordian like below:

```
#accordion.panel-group
each item in session.intents
  .panel.panel-default
    .panel-heading
      h4.panel-title
        a(data-toggle='collapse', data-parent='#accordion', href='#collapse' + item) #{item}

    #collapse#{item}.panel-collapse.collapse
      .panel-body
        .col-lg-6
          // blah blah
```

Notice that I am trying to open a particular panel dynamically based on what callasible-pane ID it is assigned:

```
                  #collapse#{item}.panel-collapse.collapse
```

When I run this on a browser, I see this error:

```
  53|                         h4.panel-title
  54|                           a(data-toggle='collapse', data-parent='#accordion', href='#collapse' + item) #{item}
> 55|                       #collapse#{item}.panel-collapse.collapse
  56|                         .panel-body
  57|                           .col-lg-6
  58|                             .my-form

  Unexpected token `interpolation` expected `text`, `code`, `:`, `newline` or `eos`
     at Parser.tag (/home/shubham/workspace/EVA2.0_bootstrap/node_modules/jade/lib/parser.js:828:15)
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a valid JADE syntax.

If you want to write it like that you would have to do it like this

`div(id="collapse#{item}").panel-collapse.collapse`

Your code will look like this:

```
#accordion.panel-group
each item in session.intents
  .panel.panel-default
    .panel-heading
      h4.panel-title
        a(data-toggle='collapse', data-parent='#accordion', href='#collapse' + item) #{item}

    div(id="collapse#{item}").panel-collapse.collapse
      .panel-body
        .col-lg-6
          // blah blah
```

### Test:

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/rema/pen/ZQWboq)

Comment: Is there a better way to do that in Jade? I ask this because you say "if you want to write it like that..." as if there is a better way. I am just getting started with Jade, will love to know if I could improve.

Comment: This is not the better way, this is the only way, because when you say #{var} (interpolating a var) you only interpolate a var when you want to turn it into a "string", this is a standard for all languages. So it turns a var into a string. So in your case you can't return it because you need a value not a "string". Another way you can write it is like this:
div(id='collapse'+item).
Sorry for late answer!

Comment: BTW: indentation is not good on this you need each to be under #accordion.panel-group not next to it. So move each and everything under it one tab
Check this example for above comment:
http://codepen.io/rema/pen/XXdYVg

Answer (score 0):

I think it's Jade problem and when i change the href to be linked to div with ID it works fine with me so in a.accordion-toggle(data-toggle='collapse', href='#cat'+cat.key) just change the href to be collapse', href='#cat'+cat.key where is cat is the item object (Category object) , also class "class="panel-collapse collapse" should be inside the div () not outside to be loaded in correct way

```
div(id="cat"+cat.key class="panel-collapse collapse").in



ul.nav.nav-pills.nav-stacked
                    each cat in categories
                        ul.nav.nav-pills.nav-stacked
                        li(class='active')
                            a.accordion-toggle(data-toggle='collapse', href='#cat'+cat.key)
                                p.large.pull-right= cat.name
                                    p
                                        | <br/>
                        div(id="cat"+cat.key class="panel-collapse collapse").in
                            .panel-body
                                ul.nav.nav-pills.nav-stacked
                                if cat.subcategories.length
                                    each sub in cat.subcategories
                                        ul.nav.nav-pills.nav-stacked
                                        li(role="presentation" class='active')
                                        a.accordion-toggle(href='/blog/' +cat.key+'/'+sub.key+'/sub')
                                            p.pull-right= sub.name
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Perhaps explain your solution for readers to understand.